# Update record in EF4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Im newbie to Asp.NetMVC3.I am trying to update my record using EF4.
Heres my code for updating the record.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie movies)
    {
        using(var db = new AmsecDevTestEntities1())
        {
            db.Movies.Attach(db.Movies.Single(m => m.Id == movies.Id));
            db.Movies. (movies); //Im stuck here how can i update the record

        }
    }
```

I tried to use **db.Movies.ApplyCurrentValues(movies);**.But im getting an error saying that context doesnot exists here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the row like this:

```
var movie = db.Movies.Single(m => m.Id == movies.Id);
movie.Name = "Pulp Fiction";
db.SaveChanges();
```

OR

```
context.Entry(movies).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

See MSDN article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj592676.aspx, look at this section:

> Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context

Do note if you are attaching you really need to make sure this is happening in a new context. If an entity with the same id is already tracked by the context you will get an error.

Comment: I've lots of fields to update.How can i do this in single go?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this

Change the state of the entity to Modified:

db.Movies1.Attach(movie);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(movie, EntityState.Modified);
db.SaveChanges();

This marks all properties of movie as modified and will send an UPDATE statement to the database which includes all column values, no matter if the values really changed or not.
```